# Compile java class from php with shell_exec

Tags: java, php, shell-exec

I have a situation where i need to compile java classes from php using shell_exec('javac myFile.java') and then run it shell_exec('java -cp ./ myFile'). It worked fine on windows but on linux i am only able to run precompiled classes i.e. 'javac' command is not working but 'java' is working. I have tried giving absolute path to javac.exe /usr/bin... but it still does not work. And before anyone points I tried with 2>&1 at the end as well still no success. Just to add, javac and java commands work perfectly fine if used directly on terminal. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Any errors? Did you try to run `java -cp ./ myFile` from command line? Are you sure that `./` is the right path ?

Comment: absolute path to javac.exe /usr/bin ?

Comment: java -cp works fine. i have all reqd. jars in classpath environment variable. the problem is with 'javac'. it returns empty array and no class is compiled!

Comment: @jan from absolute path i mean the directory where java jdk is installed. 'which java' from command line gives this path